# Redirect to another page if the user is logged in when pressing again the login button on menu bar

Tags: functions, redirect, actions

So I have this button on the menu : "My account" that lets the user login on the website and as soon they log in they're redirect to their dashboard.

What I'm trying to achieve is if he's logged in and presses again the "My account" button to be redirect to the dashboard, because right now is redirecting to there account settings.

```
 add_action( 'template_redirect', 'dashboard_redirect' );
function dashboard_redirect()
{
    if( is_page( home_url( '/min-konto/' ) ) && ! is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/dashboard/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

I'm kinda new to WP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firest of all you have to make sure that is_page() is right. I think the right syntax is

```
is_page( 'min-konto' )
```

or

```
is_page($pageid)
```

then the function should be

```
if( is_page( $account_settings_page_id ) && is_user_logged_in() ) {
   wp_redirect( home_url( '/dashboard/' ) ); 
exit(); 
}
```

Comment: I did tried like is_page( 'min-konto' ) and ( 'myaccount ' ) because that's the slug in english , but not with is_page($pageid), how i can find out the pageid ?

Comment: Never mind about the pageid , I did found it and try it now

Comment: I suppose that 'min-konto' is the slug of the page from which you want the non logged in users to be redirected to the page with the permalinnk : www.sxample.com/dashboard

Comment: I want the logged in user to be redirect to www.sxample.com/dashboard when they pressed the button *My account*, that is the same button they use to log in in their account

Comment: `add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 2);
function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $user ) {
    // WCV Pro Dashboard
    if (class_exists('WCV_Vendors') && class_exists('WCVendors_Pro') && WCV_Vendors::is_vendor( $user->id ) ) {
        $redirect_to = get_permalink(WCVendors_Pro::get_option( 'dashboard_page_id' ));
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}`
 


This is the function that I use to redirect the user to dashboard after they log in

Comment: Ok then you have to tell me the page that My account links to when someone is logged in. Then the right usage of the function is :

`if( is_page( $account_settings_page_id ) && is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/dashboard/' ) );
        exit();
    }`

Comment: <ol> <li>User presses log in button('My account') and is not logged in</li>
<li>User is redirect to Log in page </li>
<li> After log in it's redirected to dashboard </li> 
<li> If he preses again button('My account') it's redirect to my account page but i want dashoard  </li></ol>

Comment: Then you have to find the id of the My account page and replace $account_settings_page_id with it at the function i sent before

Comment: Perfect , it worked :) : thx a lot ;)

Comment: Nice :)  I ll edit the answer then

Comment: Have one more small question , how about if just some user with certain privileges have to be there ?

Comment: You then you have to add 

`&& !current_user_can('edit_posts')`

for example if this one is the admin. edit_posts is the capability of the user role.

Comment: I want just for one user role to be more specific and that's sellers/vendors , and i don't know exactly how to do this either :P

Comment: Then the easiest way is to get a plugin for capabilities e.g. https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/  and check the capabilities that are assigned on these roles and no other role has them. So if for example the role seller has the capability 'sell' you can put `if( is_page( $account_settings_page_id ) && is_user_logged_in() && !current_user_can('sell') ) { wp_redirect( home_url( '/dashboard/' ) ); exit(); }`

Comment: I manage to do it with just ´&& !current_user_can('edit_pages')´
thank you for all your help , sending a virtual beer as a reward ;)